# Micro Cloud Foundry microconsole startup

Tags: startup, init, cloud-foundry

So ive been looking through the init.d scripts and the bashrc file and cannot find where the microconsole binary is started on initial login. Can anyone tell me where it is?

Also, does MCF support running two microconsole instances at a time? My IaaS provider only supports SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here. Your trying to host MCF with an IaaS provider? like EC2 for example? If this is the case, I would recommend installing VCAP, MCF is not kept as up to date as the VCAP project.

It's pretty straight forward to install on Ubuntu 10.04, there are instructions on the Github project page, here ... https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap

Comment: Woot, thats actually EXACTLY what i really wanted... I was trying to host MCF, but was having issues with it...